# How to send multi-line string in selenium at once?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to send multi-line strings to the input field using selenium. The string may have multiple line(more than 100). Sammple of string is like:

```
String text = "this is line1\nthis is line2\n ......\nthis is line100";
```

I tried to input the string in the input text box of form using **sendKeys(text)** but it is inputting the text line by line.

```
webElement.sendKeys(text);
```

> It is taking too much time to input the text in the input box.
>   Is there any way to sendKeys with multiple lines string at once in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by copying and pasting the text from the clipboard.

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;

StringSelection stringSelection= new StringSelection(jdText);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

webElement.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"v");
```